# String is not a String

Tags: swift, dictionary

[image]
I can't grasp what's going on. There are two issues here.

1. "Can't convert type 'String' to expected type 'String'" //am I blind, I am checking this again and again... but those are both the same Strings. And this error disappear when I type in some hardcoded String.
2. Combination of errors at the top which clearly says: there can not be Strings used as Keys in Dictionaries and error at the bottom where UserDefaults clearly return type which is forbidden by compilator few lines above.

I don't even know how to ask clearly. But where to start? In second thing I can do some workarounds, some ugly hacks, but this "String" is not "String"... ehmm... maybe someone can point me to some place where someone had similar issue?

EDITED:

```
public class PersistentDictionary<String: Codable>
```

this is trouble. As someone pointed out I am creating new Generic Type which inherits from Codable. It's like . Not sure how that landed there - it was never my intention to make it generic, but...

Comment: Post all code here directly as text as an [mcve].

Comment: Post all *relevant* code...

Comment: Sorry  - code doesn't explain thing without error messages.

Comment: Do you have another class named `String` defined somewhere?

Comment: Dan - that was my suspicion as well, but no. Maybe somewhere deep in some pods, but I in this very file I am importing "Fundation" and nothing else!

Comment: Ok - fixed. That was weird: issue was declaration of class: "public class PersistentDictionary<String: Codable>" - which was defined as generic but it clearly isn't inheriting from anything.

Comment: Not sure - should I change name of this question - that error is clearly mind blowing and if someone happens to do such stupid thing as I did xCode is clearly not helping with those errors.

Comment: Why NSDictionary?

Comment: ***should I change name of this question*** Show enough code before touching the title. If you had shown all relevant code as suggested, you would have gotten the right answer immediately.

Comment: @OOPer - all relevant code before I knew the answer could be whole project. You are spamming generic complaints which brings nothing into discussion.

Comment: When you write an initializer of a class, how the class is declared is very important, You should better show the class header at least, when showing some properties or methods or initializers. If you want to get more appropriate answer sooner, you should better respect the kind suggestions.

Comment: One more, some suggestion to improve the question is the intended role of comments.

Comment: `typealias String = Any`...?

Answer (score 1):

In this very case it was declaration of class:

```
  public class PersistentDictionary<String: Codable> {
```

//see comment which explain it in details

Comment: `class PersistentDictionary<String: Codable>` creates a new generic type called `String` that conform to Codable. That new generic type it is overshadowing the native `Swift.String` type. If you were using a single uppercase letter to represent your generic type your error would be more obvious to you. `class PersistentDictionary<C: Codable>`

Comment: You are 100% right. Fun fact: that was never my intention to make it generic and even looking at it I've seen it as narrowing allowed types of Dictionary, not defining generic type - I seen what I wanted to write not what I've written :)